# How to list LOGIN + ROLE in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, security, scripting, logins, role

I'm looking for an answer but I can't find it. Just a lot of long scripts.

I need to list Login | Role (`sysadmin`, `dbcreator`, etc ) but I can't find a table to join.

I have this for now:

```
SELECT 
    name AS Login_Name, type_desc AS Account_Type
FROM 
    sys.server_principals 
WHERE 
    TYPE IN ('U', 'S', 'G')
    AND name NOT LIKE '%##%'
ORDER BY 
    name, type_desc
```

I need another column with the role.

With table should I search for it?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I see that `sys.syslogins` has some information with binary.

Is it possible to use a CASE here? ( Programming is not my best )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, don't use `sys.syslogins` - this is a deprecated compatibility view that is only there so people have time to change their existing code based on SQL Server 2000. Also, I'm completely unclear how you think a `CASE` expression will help you. You need to join to `sys.server_role_members` to find out which logins belong to which roles, and then back to `sys.server_principals` again to get the name of each role.

```
SELECT p.name AS Login_Name, p.[type_desc] AS Account_Type,r.name AS [Role]
FROM sys.server_principals AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_role_members AS rm
ON p.principal_id = rm.member_principal_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals AS r
ON rm.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
AND r.[type] = 'R'
WHERE p.[type] IN ('U', 'S', 'G')
and p.name not like '%##%'
ORDER BY p.name, p.[type_desc];
```

(I'm not sure what value you expect from the second `ORDER BY` column here.)

If you want only a single row per login:

```
SELECT p.name AS Login_Name, p.[type_desc] AS Account_Type,
  Roles = STUFF((SELECT N',' + r.name
    FROM sys.server_role_members AS rm
    INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS r
    ON rm.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
    WHERE rm.member_principal_id = p.principal_id
    ORDER BY r.name 
    FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,N'')
FROM sys.server_principals AS p
WHERE p.[type] IN ('U', 'S', 'G')
and p.name not like '%##%'
ORDER BY p.name;
```

Comment: Hello Aaron. Thanks again for the fast answer. But why I can only see SysAdmin Logins?

I comented the "where" but its showing me only SysAdmin. 

Is there a way to show every Login with your Role?

I'm saying this because i already did this some time before to list sysadmin logins ( but they should not be ).

Again, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I was writing the comment when you updated.

When it's NULL, it's because he's Public, right?

Comment: @Rafael Try an outer join or the second query. It should list other role members too but with an inner join it would exclude anyone not in a role. (Sounds like you don't have any members of any other roles - this isn't specific to `sysadmin`.)

Comment: Thanks Aron. It's what i Need.

Think i need to study a little more about SQL sys tables.

Again, thank you. I'm really learning a lot with your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the server principles through the following query:

```
SELECT name, principal_id, sid
FROM sys.server_principals
WHERE type_desc = 'SERVER_ROLE'
```

This works in every database, so you do not need to target a specific database.